# How do I create tags for a cell?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a gaming log on a Google Sheets document and I was trying to add tags for the "genre" column but couldn't find any option myself.

Basically I'd like to make it so that the entries "RPG; FPS; Open-World" under the "Genre" would be separate words and not a single word, in order to make a detailed pie-chart of my most played genres. I know, kinda stupid, but I'd love it. Otherwise every game would have a different genre and the pie-chart would just show useless data.

Here's my log on Sheets:

[image: Log]

Unfortunately I couldn't really find much. I read something along the lines of creating a form (why?) and use it to add user-defined tags. I have no idea how that could help me. I also had a look in here but I only found formulas I had no idea how to "adapt" to my case.

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Added! Sorry for that.

Comment: I did this by counting the search results: `=COUNT(ARRAYFORMULA(SEARCH("My string to search for", 'Other sheet name'!B2:B1000)))`. Note that this uses cells from a different sheet, you might not need that

Answer (score 2):

From the question:

> Basically I'd like to make it so that the entries "RPG; FPS; Open-World" under the "Genre" would be separate words and not a single word, in order to make a detailed pie-chart of my most played genres.

Tl;Dr That is not possible in Google Sheets and in most of the spreadsheet applications. Perhaps this could be possible in [EtherCalc](https://ethercalc.net/)

In most spreadsheet apps a single cell can hold a single value, not multiple values. This is one of the core features of a spreadsheet but that doesn't mean that you can't use your data to create a pie chart as you could transform your data to the structure required by a pie chart by using formulas, Google Apps Script or the Sheets API.

---

From Wikipedia

> Each cell may contain either numeric or text data, or the results of formulas that automatically calculate and display a value based on the contents of other cells.

From the Sheets API docs

> A cell is a location at the intersection of a particular row and column, and may contain a data value.

References

- [Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/topic/9054603?hl=en&ref_topic=1382883) (topic from the Google Docs Editor Help)
- https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spreadsheet

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Do you have any other idea how I could achieve a similar result by taking advantage of Sheets' features? Or should I just resort to a single word for my genre column?

Comment: @jaKz9 If your goal is to create a pie chart, ask how to create it. In your question include a link to a demo spreadsheet with sample data.

Comment: No, sorry, I do know how to create it. I was just asking if you had any "workaround" the achieve the same result, without using tags. It seems it can't be done though, so thanks anyway.